# Why did Tom Riddle not use Petrificus Totalus on Harry in "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets"?

Tags: harry-potter

Why did Tom Riddle not use Petrificus Totalus on Harry, just to freeze Harry and let Ginny die so he can become alive again?

Comment: Why did Voldemort ever make any mistakes? His pride

Comment: Could diary Tom Riddle even preform magic properly at that stage?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! While you're here please do check out the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. That should get you up to speed on voting, accepting answers etc.

Answer (score 1):

His mother's love protected Harry. As the adult Voldemort explains in the OOTP

> “His mother left upon him the traces of her sacrifice. . . . This is old magic, I should have remembered it, I was foolish to overlook it . . . but no matter. I can touch him now.”
> Harry felt the cold tip of the long white finger touch him, and thought his head would burst with the pain. Voldemort laughed softly in his ear, then took the finger away and continued addressing the Death Eaters.
> “I miscalculated, my friends, I admit it. My curse was deflected by the woman’s foolish sacrifice, and it rebounded upon myself. Aaah . . . pain beyond pain, my friends; nothing could have prepared me for it. I was ripped from my body, I was less than spirit, less than the meanest ghost . . . but still, I was alive. What I was, even I do not know . . . I, who have gone further than anybody along the path that leads to immortality. You know my goal — to conquer death. And now, I was tested, and it appeared that one or more of my experiments had worked . . . for I had not been killed, though the curse should have done it. Nevertheless, I was as powerless as the weakest creature alive, and without the means to help myself . . . for I had no body, and every spell that might have helped me required the use of a wand. . . .

Young Riddle may well have worked out from Ginny that his older form cast a spell on Harry Potter and exploded, and did not want to repeat the experience. Better to order another creature to kill Harry.